# Transform changes width

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have span with position: absolute and width: 100%, I wanted to animate it so I added transform: scale(1.2) in hover but it changes width. How to prevent it?

```css
.caption
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.caption span.border
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}
 
.caption span.border:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some HTML to your demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the span has `display: block`, it's width is 100% of the caption.  When the span becomes scaled, the width becomes 120%.

Here are a couple of things you can try, depending on the context of this element.

- You can change the span to be `display: inline-block` so it does not have 100% width but can still be scaled.
- You can give the caption `overflow: hidden` so that even if the border overflows, it does not cause weird sizing issues.  You would need to ensure there is enough vertical space in the caption block, though.

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Auroratide/n7L8mx7b/) where you can play with each option and find which suits best.